# Qt Creator + Qt 5 + Mac OS can't display QString in debug window

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2 . Got brand-new qt5 and qt creator binaries.

I can't see QString value while debugging. Just some kind of "@45644681fd3sd"

I've built debugger-helpers, tried to add "dumper.cpp" to my project, linked against libdumper.1.0.0.dylib and nothing really helped me.

Debugger is standart Apple's GNU gdb 6.3.50.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the same problem with Qt Creator 5.0.2. I've tried installing and using GDB 7.5 and 7.6, creating a new Kit within Qt Creator to use them and making sure that "use debugging helpers" is checked in Qt Creator > Preferences > Debugger > Locals & Expressions. But no luck thus far. QStrings are still opaque - can't see the values.